# An Example Of A Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider the linear space $\mathcal{L}_\infty$ and let $x\in\mathcal{L}_\infty$ where $x=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and taking the norm of $x$ to be $\sup x_i$.   My questions are:
1). When defining $x$ in this space, is it $x=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n,...)$ or is it as it is above?
2). In showing that the norm is actually a norm, how can I show that the supremum of a sum is less than or equal to the sum of supremum.

Comment: What do you mean by "is it as it is above"?

Comment: I mean in this space, how can $x$ be defined, is it $x=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$  or $x=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n,...)$?

Comment: In most cases I'm aware of, it is the second, i.e., $x$ is an infinite sequence.

Comment: Ok. Any help on the second question?

Comment: To "show that the supremum of a sum is less than or equal to the sum of supremum" you would use the definition of supremum.

Answer (score 2):

1. The elements of $\ell_\infty$ are infinite sequences.
2. To show $\|x+y\|_\infty\le \| x\|_\infty+\| y\|_\infty$, use the following strategy:

   a)  for every $n$, $|x_n|\le \| x\|_\infty$ and $|y_n|\le \| y\|_\infty$.

   b) Use the above to estimate $|x_n+y_n|$.

   c) Now you have an upper bound for $|x_n+y_n|$; the supremum is less than or equal to an upper bound.